# Why isnt my middleware working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin-middleware

I've tried to add my own middleware, it does not work :-)

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OWIN IS WORKING");

        app.Use<CustomMiddleware>();
    }
}

public class CustomMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    }
}
```

The WriteLine is so it enters the Configuration per request to the server, but my CustomMiddleware Invoke aint triggered.

Anye clue?

Comment: You should really have a constructor in the `CustomMiddleware` class that takes in the next middleware item and calls it in sequence. Otherwise, your pipeline stops here.

Comment: @DavidG Good point. And how do I...? I just wanted to create a middleware that checks if header Content-Type is set. if not return 400

Comment: Is this for ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Plain ol' asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need constructor have next `delegate`.

So your code should change like the below:

```
public class CustomMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        await _next();
    }
}
```